# python2.6 getting How do i get output from Solaris11 command into a varaible line by line

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python.

Would like to know How do I get output from a Solaris11 command into a variable line by line.
With the intention of extracting the output one line at a time.

The Solaris 11 command pkg list | pkg info, provides a detailed list of all the installed packages on the server. I am only interested in pulling the Name, Description, Version, size.

I have the following code so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os
import commands

'''
PCI package compliance

The purpose of this program is to pull package information from
Solaris11 and place that information into a comma separated file that can be read by excel.
the information in question is Name, Description, Version, size
'''

pkg_list = commands.getoutput('pkg list | pkg info')

pkgname = pkg_list[0]

print pkgname
```

However the pkgname = pkg_list[0] does not give me the entire line that starts with name. 
pkgname = pkg_list[10] will print only the N. So I believe my problem is figuring out how to format the input so that I can output 4 fields per record.

As requested, here is some sample output from the "pkg list | pkg info" command.

```
       Name: x11/xmag
       Summary: xmag - magnify parts of the screen
   Description: The xmag program allows you to capture a static image of a
                portion of an X screen, and display it magnified.
      Category: System/X11
         State: Installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 1.0.5
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 0.175.2.0.0.42.1406
Packaging Date: Mon Jun 23 21:58:12 2014
          Size: 115.81 kB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/x11/xmag@1.0.5,5.11-0.175.2.0.0.42.1406:20140623T215812Z

          Name: x11/xvidtune
       Summary: xvidtune - video mode tuner for Xorg servers
   Description: Xvidtune is a client interface to the X server video mode
                extension (XFree86-VidModeExtension), allowing a user to
                interactively adjust existing video modes.
      Category: System/X11
         State: Installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 1.0.3
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 0.175.2.0.0.42.1406
Packaging Date: Mon Jun 23 21:58:16 2014
          Size: 65.90 kB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/x11/xvidtune@1.0.3,5.11-0.175.2.0.0.42.1406:20140623T215816Z
```

Update: The command below:

```
print pkg_list.split('\n')[0]+","+pkg_list.split('\n')[1]+','+pkg_list.split('\n')[4]+','+pkg_list.split('\n')[5]
```

Produces the output:

```
Name: archiver/gnu-tar,       Summary: GNU version of the tar archiving utility,      Category: Development/GNU,         State: Installed
```

now I need to loop through the items. Any suggestions?

Update Sept 9, 6:41

All right, I am almost there. The follow code loops through all the packages on the system:

```
#! /usr/bin/python


import os 
import commands

'''
PCI package compliance

The purpose of this program is to pull package information from
Solaris11 and place that information into a comma separated file that can be read by excel.
the information in question is Name, Description, Version, size
'''




for list in (commands.getoutput('pkg list | awk -F" " \'{print $1}\'').split('\n')):
        #command1 = "pkg info "+list
        pkg_list = commands.getoutput("pkg info %s" %list)
        print pkg_list.split('\n')[0]+","+pkg_list.split('\n')[1]+','+pkg_list.split('\n')[2] #+','+pkg_list.split('\n')[5]
```

Gives the following output:

```
Name: compress/pixz,       Summary: parallel indexing version of XZ,   Description: pixz compresses and decompresses files using multiple
```

However, I had to chop off the last piece, namely element[5]. With the code added in I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Documents/python/pci3", line 22, in <module>
    ver = pkg_list.split('\n')[5]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any suggestions on how to get the final element back in?

Update Sept 9, 7:00 PM

I was able to remove the white spaces from the output. See below. However, I still need to get the last element printed namely element 5 (#+pkg_list.split('\n')[5])

```
#! /usr/bin/python


import os 
import commands

'''
PCI package compliance

The purpose of this program is to pull package information from
Solaris11 and place that information into a comma separated file that can be read by excel.
the information in question is Name, Description, Version, size
'''




for list in (commands.getoutput('pkg list | awk -F" " \'{print $1}\'').split('\n')):
        #command1 = "pkg info "+list
        pkg_list = commands.getoutput("pkg info %s" %list)
        #print pkg_list.split('\n')[0]+","+pkg_list.split('\n')[1]+','+pkg_list.split('\n')[2] #+','+pkg_list.split('\n')[5]
        output = []
        output = pkg_list.split('\n')[0]+","+pkg_list.split('\n')[1]+','+pkg_list.split('\n')[2]
        print output.replace(" ","")
```

Comment: Can you add the sample output of `pkg list | pkg info` or the contents or variable pkg_list? I believe you are using indexing 11 characters (10 + 1 for index 0) into the string stored at pkg_list. You likely want to split the output on newlines and process it a line at a time.

Comment: sample output added.

Comment: Can you try `print pkg_list.split('\n')[0]`

Comment: looks like you hit the nail on the head. print pkg_list.split('\n')[0]+","+pkg_list.split('\n')[1]+','+pkg_list.split('\n')[4]+','+pkg_list.split('\n')[5] is what I need. Not sure I completely understand how this works? does the items in the array change because of the split function? Now i just need to figure out how to loop through them.

Comment: Which part don't you understand or can use additional clarification? Looping through them using offsets like you did above won't work since description section has differing number of lines (2 in xmag and 3 in xvidtune). I'd recommend using regular expression to take care of this. Post over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45599/solaris-11-how-to-get-pkg-properties-in-machine-readable-format has example shell code, but probably better to use python re module. As an different alternative you can use pkg contents command described in other post to only extract data you care about.